# Using Jetpack to track an Ajax powered blog

Tags: plugin-jetpack

I am setting up my own blog, and I'm having fun making it with Ajax calls to WP API (plus a default php fallback). Everything works properly so far, but what's making me wonder is how to make Jetpack work properly. I know that with Google Analytics I could send a pageview event, do you know if this is possible with Jetpack?

I was thinking of firing something like a Jetpack pageview event using Javascript. Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Obviously this belongs in jetpack support forum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's documented, but you can probably use `_stq.push`. Here's what I see on one of my sites with WordPress.com Stats:

```
_stq.push([ 'view', {v:'ext',j:'1:3.8.2',blog:'1234567',post:'123',tz:'3',srv:'example.org'} ]);
```

Comment: Mh, I need to know what those j, blog and tz values are though

Comment: j is Jetpack api_version:version, blog is your WordPress.com blog id, tz is the timezone offset. More info here: https://github.com/Automattic/jetpack/blob/a187b583b0a47bcaf6f57834dbfc5d7c930ae035/modules/stats.php#L163

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try (I'm not on wordpress.com, hopefully it will work anyway)

Comment: If you're using Jetpack Stats then you are on WordPress.com, even if you don't actually have a WordPress.com-hosted site.